# EC2 broken pipe, lost my cmd line console

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I used ssh to connect to my EC2 ubuntu. I then run a command line server, which waits for connections and prints messages as clients connect, process, disconnect with it. This helps me see the progress of what the clients are requesting for. For some reason the ssh connection breaks, and I have to reconnect.

How to I get back my console to my command line daemon ? I need to see whats happening with the console prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use screen. On any un*x, not just EC2. Check the [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/) here, for example.